# Scala process: redirected stdout and stderr are always delayed

Tags: scala, process

I am writing a simple application that executes an external command (that takes very long time to run) while redirecting its output to another place in real time. However, no matter what I do (see below), the output from stdout and stderr always seem delayed (by 20 seconds to 1 minute). I suspect Scala only redirects the output when it is accumulated to a certain amount, but I do not know how it works under the hood. Is there any way to fix this?

I have tried

```
var lines = Seq("somecommand",blah) lines_!
dosomethingelse(lines.map{e=>println(e);e}) //problem: does not print line by line! It prints a lot of lines each time
```

And

```
var p = Seq("somecommand",blah) run ProcessLogger((o:String)=>{println(o)},(e:String)=>{println(e)}) // Same problem
```

And

```
var p = Seq("somecommand",blah) run ProcessIO(...) //manipulate java.io.InputStream directly, print each byte once it is immediately available. Same problem as above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is because of a underlying stdout issue with the command executed. Scala functions all work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

How about flush()'ing the stdout after each line (or some configurable number of lines

```
Console.flush();
```

So:

```
var lines = Seq("somecommand",blah) lines_!
dosomethingelse(lines.map{e=>println(e);Console.flush(); e})
```